# What does "ニセサマ" (nisesama) mean? It was in Chuunibyou

Tags: translation, readings, names, anime, puns

I was watching Chuunibyou and noticed this writing on Nibutani's back:
"**ニセサマ**". I looked up what that meant and found nothing, so my question is **what does ニセサマ translate to**?

Note: I know kana very well, but know virtually no kanji or actual grammar or anything (pretty much just [犬]{いぬ} and how to say what my name is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an onslaught of wordplay.

The character's name is 丹生谷【にぶたに】 森夏【しんか】. Her given name is made up from two *kanji*, 森 and 夏 which both have more than one reading — a *kun'yomi* (*kun* reading) and an *on'yomi* (*on* reading).

- 森 "forest" has *on'yomi* しん and *kun'yomi* もり
- 夏 "summer" has *on'yomi* か and *kun'yomi* なつ

森夏 is also called モリサマ, which is a play on words (or rather play on readings) since 夏 would be "summer" in English, hence サマー in *katakana*, which is close to 様【さま】. Of course 様 is a polite honorific, whence 森夏 → もりサマー → モリサマ (森様) would be something like "Ms. Mori". (Of course 様 doesn't mean "Ms." in general.)

Now, her family name is 丹生谷【にぶたに】, which is quite a rare reading. The reading of the first *kanji* に is standard, but the second *kanji* 生 has a more standard reading せい. Putting them together gives にせい, which sounds like 偽【にせ】 "fake". Combining this with 夏 read サマー or サマ (= 様) we get that 丹生谷 森夏 → 丹生夏 → にせいサマー → ニセサマ (偽様) would be something like "Ms. Fake". Again, just like "Ms. Mori" it is a nickname derived from different readings of parts of her name.

Of course to say it just means "fake summer" is missing out on the wordplay, but this often happens in subtitles, which cannot translate such play on words (or play on readings).

Answer (score 3):

ニセサマ means 偽物{にせもの}のモリサマ(Fake Morisama). Morisama is a nickname that the main character 丹生谷 森夏 used in internet. One day, a girl who said "I am Morisama" appeared. I think this girl wrote ニセサマ on Morisama's back so that she showed real Morisama was fake Morisama.

Source: https://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/tebuku/32879725.html

Answer (score -3):

ニセ = false
サマ = summer

It should explain all you need to know.

Comment: By saying this is all they need to know you're expecting quite a lot from somebody who does not know any *kanji* besides 犬.

Comment: it's self-explanatory. As long as he knows English it would be enough. :/